# My plugin doesn't stop on Breakpoints

Tags: vb.net, breakpoints

I'm seeing strange behaviour with a plugin for Readsoft that I'm developing.

I want it to stop on a breakpoint but it doesn't. The msgbox just before the place I put the breakpoint is displaying correctly, and the one right after it too.

I need your help because I don't have any clue of what the problem is.

Thanks for your help!

[here is the class with the breakpoint I want to stop to](http://screencast.com/t/Fn8SkYeCu)

[here is the ReadSoft programm with the Msgbox displayed after the breakpoint line where debug didn't stop](http://screencast.com/t/2CAptUlld)

PS : I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional, coding in VB.NET

Comment: Recompile code ? restart VS ? VS instances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally find the answer and think it can help.

So my problem was coming from the fact that I was running my project under Visual Studio 2010, but this project was originally created on Visual Studio 2005 and running on .NET framework 2.

Simply changing the framework to framework 4 has solved my problem.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've run into this problem I can usually clear it up by selecting Build > Clean Solution, then Build > Rebuild Solution. I think it's caused when the debug symbols get out of sync with the code.

If that doesn't work, I'll make sure I'm in Debug mode (Release mode enables optimizations that can occasionally make changes so you't can set the breakpoint on the line you want) and I'll clear all of the breakpoints - Debug > Delete All Breakpoints, then set the breakpoint again.

Comment: thanks for answering!
how can I check I m in Debug mode please?

Comment: There is usually a dropdown on the toolbar immediately to the right of the "Run" (right green arrow). If you don't see it, you can go to Build > Configuration Manager, then select the Active solution configuration.

Comment: One additional thought, since you mentioned that you're developing a plug-in. I've had cases where the assembly that is actually being loaded isn't my most recent version (that is, the other app. is loading the wrong version/another copy of the assembly). In those cases searching for the assembly and deleting the other version fixed the issue.

Comment: Actually the Assembly is the correct one because it takes the msgbox I added for checking if the application goes to the breakpointed line.

Comment: any other ideas?
I'm stuck and programming without debugging is being very hard

Comment: You need to describe what you're seeing and how you're running your code in more detail (edit your question and add more info). Additionally, what do your breakpoints look like (do they change from a solid color to anything else?)

Answer (score 0):

When I launch my app it automatically launch the ReadSoft programm it will run into as on this

[here is the properties file that launch the ReadSoft programm it is going to run into](http://screencast.com/t/vgHZghETs)